# Can't get sidebar nav to display properl

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I can't get my child `<ul>` to display properly. When the dropdown is open, it displays underneath the rest of the menu. What I want is the rest of the `<li>` to move down to make room for the dropdown.

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two
    <ul>
      <li>Two One</li>
      <li>Two Two</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    Three
    <ul>
      <li>Four</li>
      <li>Five</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
  width: 250px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
}

.nav li {
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav li:hover {
  background-color: #008cba;
}

.nav ul {
  display: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.nav ul li {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  color: #000;
  border-bottom: #464646 solid 1px;
}

.nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #464646;
}

.active {
  display: initial!important;
  tranistion: 0.5s;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul.nav li ").click(function() {
    $(this).find("ul").toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

Comment: Please create a fiddle so community can check easily.

Comment: @M3Dev https://jsfiddle.net/rmmocbwr/

Comment: Remove height from .nav li see here: https://jsfiddle.net/rmmocbwr/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should:

- Add "position: relative" to your ".nav ul"
- Remove "height: 40px" from your ".nav li"
- Change in your ".active" class from "display: initial !important" to "display: block !important"

Here are the relevant classes:

```
.nav li {
  background-color: #000;
  display: block;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav ul {
  display: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}

.active {
  display: block !important;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```